# Change images if window is resized with javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the source of the loaded images, when the window is resized. With this code they change only when the page is reloaded.
I can't use JQuery, only javascript.

```
function Resize () {
if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    var Photo = "photop" + i + ".jpg";
    photos.push(photo);
} else {
    var Photo = "photo" + i + ".png";
    photos.push(photo); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [onresize event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp).

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
      var Photo = "photop" + i + ".jpg";
      photos.push(photo);
    } else {
      var Photo = "photo" + i + ".png";
      photos.push(photo); }
};
```